# Searching for a column based on string, then sumif for multiple criteria in that column (excel 2007)

Tags: excel, sum, match

I have a large data set on a sheet named Program Data that (very roughly) looks like this:

```
  5              12         13             28          32        
Column E .... Column N   Column O ...  Column AB    Column AC ...  

Existing        CCS       Auto           425.25       36.89
New             RCS       Auto            32.65      189.50
Existing        CCS       Auto           100.00       50.00
```

The numbers above the column names are significant and are how I am required to find/reference the columns, but they do NOT correlate with A=1, B=2, etc. I have a cell, AK2, that tells what the number above these column is. I need to create a formula that looks for the column that has the specified number, then sumif on that specific column. Right now I have the following formula:

```
=SUMIFS(INDEX('Program Data'!A:GA,0,MATCH("*"&Ak2&"*" ,'Program Data'!1:1,0)),

 'Program Data'!$N:$N,"CCS",'Program Data'!$E:$E,"Existing",'Program Data'!O:O,"Auto")
```

Where the above is searching for the number that is specified in AK2, then adding up everything in that column that is "CCS","Existing", and "Auto" (columns E, N, and O, respecively). So for the above table, if AK2=28, then I want the values in column AB, so the formula would return 525.25. If AK2=32, then I'd want column AC, so the formula would return 86.89.

The problem is that the formula above keeps getting an NA on the MATCH statement, though the text in AK2 and the number match perfectly and there are values that meet the criteria in the sumif statement. I can't figure out the problem. Any suggestions are appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should dispense with the wildcards in `MATCH` function, try just

`=SUMIFS(INDEX('Program Data'!A:GA,0,MATCH(AK2,'Program Data'!1:1,0)),'Program Data'!$N:$N,"CCS",'Program Data'!$E:$E,"Existing",'Program Data'!O:O,"Auto")`

Comment: Oh my gosh, I feel so foolish! Thanks for your eye on that -- I was modifiyin an older, obsolete formula and needlessly carried it over. Thanks for the help!